# iOS 14 - How to open Default Mail App programmatically?

Tags: ios, email, ios14, mailto

With iOS14 users can set different email client apps as their default.

**Is there a way to open the selected default mail app programmatically?**

Using `mailto:` URLs, after setting the default mail app to Gmail, don't do anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently you have to add `mailto` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to make it work.

Comment: the issue with this solution is that it will open the compose new mail in the clients.. do you know another way that open just the default without any action @peter-lendvay

Answer (score 7):

Add following to info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```

Comment: `http` and `https` do not need to be in that list

Comment: I didn't know how to edit the info.plist file directly, so [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et2Mo.png) is how it looks like in Xcode 14 in Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this in the doc [url_launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), that's why it didn't work for me:

> URL schemes are only supported if there are apps installed on the device that can support them. For example, iOS simulators don't have a default email or phone apps installed, so can't open `tel:` or `mailto:` links.