# mailto: scheme and custom mail client in iOS 14

Tags: ios, ios14

If I change the default mail iOS client into another one, `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL` returns `false`. For default client this method returns `true`.

But if I call `UIApplication.shared.open` directly, a custom email client app opens correctly.
Does somebody know, what's is the problem? Is it a iOS bug? Or maybe I can detect email client using another way?

URL: `mailto://some@email.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 14 - How to open Default Mail App programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447460/ios-14-how-to-open-default-mail-app-programmatically)

Comment: @Ben yes. mine answer is correct too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `Info.plist`.
Just add (or create) a new item `mailto` for this property.